# Moving keys out of std::map<> &&

Tags: c++, stdmap

I'd like to have let's say `getKeys()` function getting not-copiable keys out of a `map`:

```
class MyObj {
  // ... complex, abstract class...
};

struct Comparator { bool operator()(std::unique_ptr<MyObj> const &a, std::unique_ptr<MyObj> const &b); };

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObj>> getKeys(std::map<std::unique_ptr<MyObj>, int, Comparator> &&map) {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObj>> res;
  for (auto &it : map) {
    res.push_back(std::move(it.first));
  }
  return res;
}
```

But it is not working because the key in `it` (`.first`) is `const`. Any tips how to solve it? Note: In our environment I'm not allowed to use C++17 function `std::map::extract()`.

Is it somehow ok to use `const_cast` because `map` will be destructed anyway?

```
res.push_back(std::move(const_cast<std::unique_ptr<MyObj> &>(it.first)));
```

I want to avoid cloning `MyObj`.

I know why keys of a `std::map` container cannot be modified but is it still disallowed for a map that is going to be destructed immediately after the key modification?

Comment: Can you switch from `std::unique_ptr` to `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: Please see below the answer to myself how I workarounded the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note: In our environment I'm not allowed to use C++17 function `std::map::extract()`.

Shame - it was introduced to solve this problem.

> Is it somehow ok to use `const_cast` because map will be destructed anyway?

No.

> I want to avoid cloning `MyObj`.

Sorry; you'll need to clone the keys at least.

> I know why keys of a `std::map` container cannot be modified but is it still disallowed for a map that is going to be destructed immediately after the key modification?

Yes.

The map's internal machinery has no way of knowing that its destiny awaits.

Comment: As for the `const_cast`: [Any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime results in undefined behavior.](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#4.sentence-1).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's still disallowed. Non-const access to keys is *probably* safe if you're just going to destroy the map afterwards, but it's not guaranteed to be safe by the standard, and the `std::map` interface doesn't offer any sort of relaxation of the rules which applies to rvalue references.

What `std::map` *does* have since C++17, though, is `extract()`, which rips a key-value pair out of the map entirely and returns it as a "node handle". This node handle provides non-const access to the key. So if you were to `move` the pointer out of that node handle, the eventual destruction would happen to an empty pointer.

Example:

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

template <typename K, typename V>
std::vector<K> extractKeys(std::map<K, V> && map)
{
    std::vector<K> res;
    while(!map.empty())
    {
        auto handle = map.extract(map.begin());
        res.emplace_back(std::move(handle.key()));
    }
    return std::move(res);
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::unique_ptr<int>, int> map;
    map.emplace(std::make_pair(std::make_unique<int>(3), 4));

    auto vec = extractKeys(std::move(map));

    return *vec[0];
}
```

Comment: Removing key after key likely results in quite a number of tree-rebalancing. Still this seems to be the only fully legal way go get the keys out again...

Comment: @Aconcagua Agreed. I think in this circumstance I'd probably use a combination of `const_cast` and hoping for the best. :-D

Comment: Have you noticed that OP is not allowed to use C++17? It seems to me that he/she is aware of `std::map::extract`, just can't use it. The second part of your answer seems completely superfluous to me, including the whole code. (Also note that your `extractKeys` function will accept only `map`s with default both comparator and allocator template arguments, which is not OP's case.)

Comment: Nope, I missed that bit of the OP's message (but remember that SO answers are meant to be widely applicable, not just applicable to the original questioner). The code is intended to illustrate the technique, not to be used unmodified.

Comment: They're supposed to be applicable to the question though

Answer (score 0):

Answers persuaded me that I should avoid const_cast-ing. After some analysis I realized that usage of my map is quite isolated in the code so I could do a small refactor to avoid the const-issue.

Here is the result:

```
class MyObj {
  // ... complex, abstract class...
};

struct Comparator { bool operator()(MyObj const *a, MyObj const *b); };

// key is a pointer only, value holds the key object and the effective "value"
struct KeyAndVal { std::unique_ptr<MyObj> key; int val; };
using MyMap = std::map<MyObj *, KeyAndVal, Comparator>;

// Example how emplace should be done
auto myEmplace(MyMap &map, std::unique_ptr<MyObj> key, int val) {
  auto *keyRef = key.get();  // to avoid .get() and move in one expr below
  return map.emplace(keyRef, KeyAndVal{ std::move(key), val });
}

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObj>> getKeys(MyMap map) {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObj>> res;
  for (auto &it : map) {
    res.push_back(std::move(it.second.key));
  }
  // here 'map' is destroyed but key references are still valid
  // (moved into return value).
  return res;
}
```