# Two std::unique_ptr pointing to the same object – undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Assuming the following code:

```
T* t = new T();
std::unique_ptr<T> p1(t);
std::unique_ptr<T> p2(t);
```

Obviously, now two `std::unique_ptr`s point to one and the same object. Is this state per se already undefined behaviour? I couldn't find appropriate hints in the standard, so I would answer 'no' so far, but want to get re-assured.

Side note: This question is not about undefined behaviour yielded by double deletion later on, which could be avoided by one of the pointers `release()`ing its content at the right time...

*Edit:*

**As from comments and answers given arising, too, such multiple ownership is *dangerous* and should *not* be applied in real code, even *if* undefined behaviour actually can be avoided! This question treats a thought experiment only!**

Comment: I'm not on the committee so I can't say for sure but the [draft](http://eel.is/c++draft////unique.ptr.single#ctor-6) indicates that the requirement is that the `unique_ptr` must own the pointer passed to it after the constructor is finished. Because this would leave both `p1` and `p2` in ownership I would say, *Yes this is undefined behavior*.

Comment: It is the double free which is UB. Here is dangerous code which won't pass my review.

Comment: @Jarod42 Fully agree on the dangerous code. Experimenting in thoughts *only* to get a solution for [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58268530/moving-keys-out-of-stdmap) (or even if `extract` *was* available, avoid re-arranging the map again and again), idea would have been a separate struct releasing the smart pointer in destructor if a copy has been created... True solution in my eyes, though, if *really* a performance issue, would be not using smart pointers in the map in that case...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically there is no UB until you do something that causes a double delete.  The constructor of `std::unique_ptr` [does not state that the pointer should not already be owned,](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/unique.ptr.single.ctor) so in the strictest sense of the word it is not undefined behavior to have the pointer owed by two object

That said, semantically the code is not correct and this should not be done.  You are breaking the unique ownership guarantee that `std::unique_ptr` provides which means you have to be very careful how you use these objects so that you don't wind up in a double deleted state.

Comment: I'm going to disagree, it explicitly states that it should be owned after the fact. I acknowledge that this may be a defect in the standard but to me _owns_ implies single ownership. So as soon as `p2` finishes construction IMO the behavior is undefined. I suspect this is left ambiguous because the actual behavior is dependent on the deleter.

Comment: @Mgetz Exactly the same wording is used for `std::shared_ptr` later on. So apparently, the standard doesn't doesn't imply exclusive or shared ownership from 'to own'...

Comment: @Aconcagua yeah this gets complicated because technically for internally reference counted objects `unique_ptr` can be used without UB _insofar_ as a non-default deleter is used. I personally think this _specific_ situation is UB because it creates two default deleters for the same object. Thus technically a compiler could start the time travel at the final construction of P2, because even if P1 or P2 gets a `.release` before the end of scope it creates a situation where that could have happened if the scope exited at that point. Either way I'm not on the committee.

Comment: @Mgetz it can only time travel if there is an actual path that causes the double deletion.  If the OP is careful, and ensures no double delete happens on any code path, then there is no UB and no time travel can happen.  It defeats the entire purpose of using a `unique_ptr` so it should not be done, but it can be, unfortunately. All that said, the standard really should be updated to require the pointer no be already owned, to make it explicit that this use should not be done.

Comment: @NathanOliver in that case if any non `noexcept` call happens in this specific situation between those constructions and a `.release` that would IMO trigger UB as that indicates the scope could be exited and thus UB triggered. That is what I was trying to convey. That said a different constructor with a different deleter is a completely different situation. IMO the standard should be updated to specify that `default_deleter` can only be used with non-previously owned pointers. But I suspect that's implied in effect.

Comment: How hard would it be to have C style restricted pointers in C++? I don't think standard has anything similar except `unique_ptr` which is a different beast. You could then say the argument should be a restricted pointer.

Comment: @Mgetz Getting back to here after a while: `default_deleter` + already owned is too strict; what, if (in my example) `p1` has the non-defaulted deleter already? In either case we might get in to trouble anyway; what, if the UP with default deleter runs out of scope before the other one? The other one might then still be accessed in good believe of a still existing object (which, due to the semantics of the UP, appears totally valid, in contrast to a raw pointer). So this should be UB *independent* from the type of the deleter in use...

Answer (score -1):

According to cppreference, `unique_ptr` does not have copy constructors nor assignment operators just for the sole purpose of making sure assigning one `unique_ptr` to another ensures both cannot own it at the same time. The definition of constructor 2 states that `unique_ptr(pointer p)` shall take a raw pointer to construct itself.

Why doesn't constructor 2 take pointer by reference or use a pointer to pointer? This way it could ensure it has exclusive ownership of that object by setting the pointer given to it to `nullptr`. My guess is, because there are still ways to violate unique ownership rules such as making 2 pointers point to an object and passing one of them to the constructor but still have a raw pointer to the object. Because the class cannot control what is going on in the outside world it can only maintain the rules for itself.

Comment: As long as a `std::unique_ptr` can be assigned raw pointers there's no way to prevent this sitution, references don't help either. You could only assure in any case if the only way constructing a `std::unique_ptr` was via `std::make_unique` (or some equivalent new features). In any way, this doesn't answer the actual question, which is if the mere state of two UP owning the same object is already UB or if UB only occurs on double deletion occurring on both UP having run out of scope (if not prevented by whatever counter measures).